# Algorithm that finds all element in a dictionary that match the key average and the sum of value in value

Tags: algorithm, dictionary, c#-4.0, find

i have the fallowing problem:

Lets supposed that i have a dictionary that the key is the number of Days and the Value is the mount of money, like: `Dictionary Example <Days,Money>`
NOTE:Days and Money are both int.

I will input 2 values, First is the average of days that i want and the second is the mount of money that i want : Average Days: 45 / Mount of money : 50000000.

I need to think in a algorithm that run all my Dictionary and find the best way to sum the money to reach as close as possible to my input of Mount of money and the average Days.

So the output is all element of dictionary that reach the amount of money and  keeping the average day given.

Can you guys help me out with that?

Thank you :)

Comment: Could you provide more details about Days and Money classes?

Comment: This sounds like a variation of the 0-1 knapsack problem where the average is used instead of the sum?

Comment: @ReinHenrichs Well, that migh work for me. Do you have a code example of that variation of the 0-1 knapsack problem? Thank you.

Comment: @JaderAlves Sure, take a usual 0-1 knapsack implementation and use an average where it uses a sum. (Hint: an average can be implemented as the combination of a sum and a count. This also conveniently minimizes floating point error.)